# CNN model accuracy maxing out at 99%, then dropping to 50% epochs later

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm creating a CNN that can classify CT scans as positive for COVID-19 induced pnemonia and negative for healthy CT. I tested my model for 50 epochs; from epoch 1 - 10, it incrementally increases and maxes out at 99% accuracy at epoch 10. However, a couple epochs later, it drops tremendously to 44%, which is awful for a binary classification CNN. Here's my model:

```
# Loading in the dataset
traindata = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
trainingdata = traindata.flow_from_directory(
    directory="Covid-19CT/TrainingData",
    target_size=(128,128),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode="binary")
testdata = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
testingdata = testdata.flow_from_directory(
    directory="Covid-19CT/TestingData",
    target_size=(128,128),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode="binary")

# Initialize the model w/ Sequential & add layers + input and output <- will refer to the VGG 16 model architecture
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(128,128,3),filters=64,kernel_size=(2,2),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation ="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=1000, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid"))

# Compile the model
model_optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=model_optimizer, loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
# Add the callbacks
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="Covid-19.hdf5", monitor='accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto')
early = EarlyStopping(monitor='accuracy', min_delta=0, patience=50, verbose=1, mode='auto')
reduceLR = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=.5, patience=2, min_delta=0.01, mode="auto")
fit = model.fit_generator(steps_per_epoch=25, generator=trainingdata, validation_data=testingdata, validation_steps=10,epochs=50,callbacks=[checkpoint,early])
```

Here's the training accuracies:
Epoch 1/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.7703 - accuracy: 0.5495
Epoch 00001: accuracy improved from -inf to 0.54500, saving model to Covid-19.hdf5
25/25 [==============================] - 360s 14s/step - loss: 0.7646 - accuracy: 0.5450 - val_loss: 0.6984 - val_accuracy: 0.4313

Epoch 2/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 13s - loss: 0.8016 - accuracy: 0.7240
Epoch 00002: accuracy improved from 0.54500 to 0.73250, saving model to Covid-19.hdf5
25/25 [==============================] - 374s 15s/step - loss: 0.7868 - accuracy: 0.7325 - val_loss: 4.4926 - val_accuracy: 0.6375

Epoch 3/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.3555 - accuracy: 0.8960
Epoch 00003: accuracy improved from 0.73250 to 0.89003, saving model to Covid-19.hdf5
25/25 [==============================] - 344s 14s/step - loss: 0.3941 - accuracy: 0.8900 - val_loss: 3.2895 - val_accuracy: 0.7000

Epoch 4/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 13s - loss: 0.2441 - accuracy: 0.9297
Epoch 00004: accuracy improved from 0.89003 to 0.93000, saving model to Covid-19.hdf5
25/25 [==============================] - 385s 15s/step - loss: 0.2387 - accuracy: 0.9300 - val_loss: 1.2085 - val_accuracy: 0.6687

Epoch 5/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 13s - loss: 0.1788 - accuracy: 0.9714
Epoch 00005: accuracy improved from 0.93000 to 0.97250, saving model to Covid-19.hdf5
25/25 [==============================] - 381s 15s/step - loss: 0.1755 - accuracy: 0.9725 - val_loss: 2.5818 - val_accuracy: 0.7125

Epoch 6/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.0642 - accuracy: 0.9844
Epoch 00006: accuracy improved from 0.97250 to 0.98000, saving model to Covid-19.hdf5
25/25 [==============================] - 363s 15s/step - loss: 0.0670 - accuracy: 0.9800 - val_loss: 4.4083 - val_accuracy: 0.7125

Epoch 7/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.0947 - accuracy: 0.9479
Epoch 00007: accuracy did not improve from 0.98000
25/25 [==============================] - 362s 14s/step - loss: 0.0937 - accuracy: 0.9500 - val_loss: 4.2777 - val_accuracy: 0.7000

Epoch 8/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 13s - loss: 0.1298 - accuracy: 0.9505
Epoch 00008: accuracy did not improve from 0.98000
25/25 [==============================] - 375s 15s/step - loss: 0.1301 - accuracy: 0.9475 - val_loss: 1.5817 - val_accuracy: 0.4688

Epoch 9/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 13s - loss: 0.0506 - accuracy: 0.9740
Epoch 00009: accuracy did not improve from 0.98000
25/25 [==============================] - 378s 15s/step - loss: 0.0486 - accuracy: 0.9750 - val_loss: 4.3898 - val_accuracy: 0.7125

Epoch 10/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.0263 - accuracy: 0.9922
Epoch 00010: accuracy improved from 0.98000 to 0.99250, saving model to Covid-19.hdf5
25/25 [==============================] - 368s 15s/step - loss: 0.0252 - accuracy: 0.9925 - val_loss: 4.3956 - val_accuracy: 0.6875

Epoch 11/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.1428 - accuracy: 0.9714
Epoch 00011: accuracy did not improve from 0.99250
25/25 [==============================] - 346s 14s/step - loss: 0.1378 - accuracy: 0.9725 - val_loss: 2.3141 - val_accuracy: 0.5188

Epoch 12/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.2058 - accuracy: 0.9479
Epoch 00012: accuracy did not improve from 0.99250
25/25 [==============================] - 343s 14s/step - loss: 0.2006 - accuracy: 0.9500 - val_loss: 2.2401 - val_accuracy: 0.6750

Epoch 13/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.0434 - accuracy: 0.9818
Epoch 00013: accuracy did not improve from 0.99250
25/25 [==============================] - 363s 15s/step - loss: 0.0417 - accuracy: 0.9825 - val_loss: 4.3546 - val_accuracy: 0.7000

Epoch 14/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.0242 - accuracy: 0.9974
Epoch 00014: accuracy improved from 0.99250 to 0.99750, saving model to Covid-19.hdf5
25/25 [==============================] - 361s 14s/step - loss: 0.0256 - accuracy: 0.9975 - val_loss: 4.4083 - val_accuracy: 0.7125

Epoch 15/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.0298 - accuracy: 0.9922
Epoch 00015: accuracy did not improve from 0.99750
25/25 [==============================] - 367s 15s/step - loss: 0.0286 - accuracy: 0.9925 - val_loss: 3.9429 - val_accuracy: 0.7125

Epoch 16/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.0045 - accuracy: 0.9974
Epoch 00016: accuracy did not improve from 0.99750
25/25 [==============================] - 338s 14s/step - loss: 0.0043 - accuracy: 0.9975 - val_loss: 4.4335 - val_accuracy: 0.7063

Epoch 17/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.2831 - accuracy: 0.9479
Epoch 00017: accuracy did not improve from 0.99750
25/25 [==============================] - 336s 13s/step - loss: 0.2750 - accuracy: 0.9500 - val_loss: 2.4855 - val_accuracy: 0.6625

Epoch 18/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 14s - loss: 1.4282 - accuracy: 0.9036
Epoch 00018: accuracy did not improve from 0.99750
25/25 [==============================] - 400s 16s/step - loss: 1.6394 - accuracy: 0.8900 - val_loss: 6.6125 - val_accuracy: 0.5688

Epoch 19/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 12s - loss: 8.0488 - accuracy: 0.4693
Epoch 00019: accuracy did not improve from 0.99750
25/25 [==============================] - 349s 14s/step - loss: 7.9984 - accuracy: 0.4731 - val_loss: 6.6125 - val_accuracy: 0.5688

Epoch 20/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 11s - loss: 7.6267 - accuracy: 0.5026
Epoch 00020: accuracy did not improve from 0.99750
25/25 [==============================] - 342s 14s/step - loss: 7.5900 - accuracy: 0.5050 - val_loss: 6.6125 - val_accuracy: 0.5688

Epoch 21/50
24/25 [===========================>..] - ETA: 12s - loss: 8.2656 - accuracy: 0.4609

I think I'll end up replacing Early Stopping with a dropout layer, but can't understand the reason for such a drop in accuracy. While the model was probably overfitting with the 99% accuracy, why the sudden drop?

Comment: You need to look at val accuracy and stop training when it starts falling. Then you should compare what you ve got to a baseline.

Comment: Can someone explain why this comment has 4 users flagging it? Is it because it doesn't solve the steep drop in accuracy and just ignores it?

Comment: These are not flags, these are upvotes telling that 4 people support what was told. The drop in train accuracy is definitely worthwile to consider from theoritacl standpoint, but practically speaking you need to look at val accuracy, as the comment telling you.

Comment: The drop in train accuracy can be for any reason: model has fallen into local minima, exploding gradient, anything, that can be found closely investigating the loss surface and gradients, but it's not so intersting practically.

Comment: Ohh, okay thank you. I'll take a look at the val accuracy, another user suggested switching the monitor to val loss instead of accuracy so I'll do that. It's interesting because I've never had such a strange uprise and steep downfall in accuracy before like this, I'll look more into the reasons you suggested. Thanks Sergey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as suggested about early stopping or training for less epochs if you wish, I notice you are monitoring "accuracy" in your callbacks. It is usually best to monitor the validation loss and save the model with the lowest loss. Validation loss is an indication of how well your model generalizes to unseen images. Just an FYI I notice you are saving the entire model. That's fine but it greatly slows down the time it takes to complete training. Try just saving the weights in the checkpoint callback. It is much faster especially if you have a large model.  Then after training is complete run model.load_weights to do predictions. Then you can save the entire model with model.save. All this does not address the issue of why your model training loss starts to sky rocket after the tenth epoch. I can't figure it out. Point me to the location of the data set in a comment and I will see if I can duplicate the problem. As a quick check how many training samples and how many test samples do you have? You want to go through your validation set once per epoch. So you need to set the validation_batch_size such that the number of validation samples divided by the validation_batch_size is an integer. Use that integer as validation_steps. Below is a piece of code that given a directory path and a maximum batch size you can allow based on memory capacity (b_max) will give you the batch_size and steps. It goes through the directory (for example test_dir) and adds up the count of all the files within all the sub directories (variable length) then determines the batch size and steps.

```
def get_bs(dir,b_max):
    # dir is the directory containing the samples, b_max is maximum batch size to allow based on your memory capacity
    # you only want to go through test and validation set once per epoch this function determines needed batch size ans steps per epoch
    length=0
    dir_list=os.listdir(dir)
    for d in dir_list:
        d_path=os.path.join (dir,d)
        length=length + len(os.listdir(d_path))
    batch_size=sorted([int(length/n) for n in range(1,length+1) if length % n ==0 and length/n<=b_max],reverse=True)[0]  
    return batch_size,int(length/batch_size), length
```

If you run this on your test directory you should get batch_size=79, steps= 14 and length = 1106 with b_max set to 80.

Comment: Hello! I'll do as suggested about the val loss and saving just the weights. Thank you for the suggestions. Unfortunately I'm not sure where I got the dataset, I was looking through kaggle for COVID-19 CTs but the datasets were pretty small, so I went through research papers instead, but thank you for offering to take the time to duplicate the issue. I really appreciate it. My file structure is /test /noncovid /covid and /train /noncovid /covid and I have 4167 training samples belonging to the 2 classes and 1106 testing samples belonging to the 2 classes.

Comment: I am just really curious about what the problem is. Usually I can figure it out but right now I am stuck. Think I may try your code with a different data set and see if the problem occurs.

Comment: By the way another FYI. It is best to go through your validation set just once per epoch. To do that you need to set validation_step_size so that the number of validation samples divided by the number of validation_steps is an integer. See modified answer.

Comment: I noticed you have a training batch_size=16 and you specify steps_per_epoch=25. So for any epoch you only train on 25 X 16=400 samples. In model.fit remove the steps_per_epoch, fit will automatically use all the samples (plus a few more). Also look through the images in the train directory and see if any of the images are messed up.

Comment: Oh okay. I checked through my training samples and it seems like all the images are fine. One user suggested that it may be the result of an exploding gradient which after I searched up makes the most sense: the accuracy shoots up and down because the model is unstable. I think that is the most likely culprit, thank you for all the help and please let me know if you have any further thoughts.

Comment: built lots of image models. Never seen that behavior it has to be something else but without the data set I can't figure it out.

Comment: I'm gonna keep trying to search for it again, retrace the keywords and see if I can come across the dataset again. I'm also curious to know what the cause of this issue is. If I'm able to find the dataset, I'll let you know!